# how to exclude `x` from `range(n)` using numpy

Tags: python, list, numpy, range

I want to create an array of numbers from 1 to `n` without the number `x`,

is there a "prettier" way to do it instead of `[i for i in range(n) if i != x]`?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using advanced indexing with [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html).

```
np.arange(n)[np.r_[0:x, x+1:n]]
```

---

```
def myrange(n, exclude):
    return np.arange(n)[np.r_[0:exclude, exclude+1:n]]
```

```
>>> myrange(10, exclude=3)
array([0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

#### `Timings`

```
%timeit myrange(10000000, 7008)
1 loop, best of 3: 79.1 ms per loop

%timeit other(10000000, 7008)
1 loop, best of 3: 952 ms per loop
```

where

```
def myrange(n, exclude):
    return np.arange(n)[np.r_[0:exclude, exclude+1:n]]

def other(n, exclude):
    return [i for i in range(n) if i != x]
```

Comment: Preferably, if I am creating a function for it, shouldn't I just use `[i for i in range(n) if i != x]` as it is easier to read? is there any advantage for advanced indexing in this case?

Comment: @Tomergt45 Sure is easier to read, but way slower. The function name `myrange` and some docstrings should make this readable, and you'd still benefit from the fast speed. I've added some timings to illustrate. Another detail is that a list comprehension yields a python list, while `np.arange` +`np.r_` gives a numpy array directly

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) :

```
for a in itertools.chain(range(x), range(x+1, n)):
    print(a)
```

or

```
list(itertools.chain(range(x), range(x+1, n)))
```

I don't know why, but `[itertools.chain(range(x), range(x+1, n))]` doesn't work though.

EDIT: Thanks to @rafaelc for how to make it work on square brackets.

```
[*itertools.chain(range(x), range(x+1, n))]
```

Comment: `[*itertools.chain(range(x), range(x+1, n))]` would work. You have to unpack it

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate two ranges:

```
np.concatenate((np.arange(x), np.arange(x + 1, n)))
```

You can also delete an item:

```
np.delete(np.arange(n), x)
```

You can mask:

```
mask = np.ones(n, dtype=bool)
mask[x] = False
np.arange(n)[mask]
```

You can even use a masked array, depending on your application:

```
a = np.ma.array(np.arange(n), mask=np.zeros(n, dtype=bool))
a.mask[x] = True
```